# How to user listen the songs after purchasing their songs or products using Drupal commerce?

Tags: users, commerce, files

I am using [Drupal commercekickstart.](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). I have installed [Commerce file module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file)  and [Commerce license module also](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license).If user purchasing their product after that their can download the files at the same time user can listen the songs through player inside this project.Is it possible? Anyone guide to me?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably place a view on the confirmation / download page to link to the mp3 inside html5 audio tags.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="mymusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

You could make the default view in a block, place it on the confirmation page where the link to download the mp3 is, and get the mp3 file with a contextual filter with a default value of get ID from URL.

Comment: can u explain it? I want to music store.

Comment: At the end where they are given the link to download the file, use views and rewrite results, or override with a field template to load the file inside HTML5 audio tags. That will create the player you asked for. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all